# In App Purchasing - EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

I've been experiencing some weird issues trying to test In-app purchasing(iOS 8+ Swift 1.2). I have a consumable product in the iTunes connect account and I am able to retrieve the product and product details fine. At the point where I want to initiate the purchase, the line of code before the EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash is in

```
//Transaction has been made
func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {

    if(list.count == 0){
        return
    }

    //code
    for transaction:AnyObject in transactions{
        var trans = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction
        println(trans.error)

        switch trans.transactionState {
        case .Purchasing:
            println("Purchasing...The transaction is being processed by the App Store.")
        case .Purchased:
            println("Buy, ok unlock iap here")
            println(p.productIdentifier)
            queue.finishTransaction(trans)
            let prodID = p.productIdentifier! as String
            switch prodID {
                case iapID:
                    println("send submission")
                    saveSuperSubmission()
                default:
                    println("IAP not Setup")
            }
        case .Failed:
            println("buy error")
            queue.finishTransaction(trans)
        default:
            println("updatedTransactions: \(trans.transactionState.rawValue)")
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

After hitting the **.Purchasing** case it immediately crashes. Now on the physical device after asking for my password, a confirmation prompt to buy the product appears and when i select to buy, another prompt states "This In-App Purchase has already been bought". Xcode doesn't show any of my code in the trace once the crash happens. It shows UIApplicationMain and what looks like the following

```
  0x2daf0a04 <+1436>: blx    0x2e1ae2c8                ; symbol stub for: CFDictionaryRemoveAllValues$shim
    0x2daf0a08 <+1440>: ldr    r0, [sp, #0x2c]
    0x2daf0a0a <+1442>: ldr    r1, [sp, #0x18]
```

1. Why does it care that a product has already been bought if it is of a "Consumable" type? I expect this to be purchased numerous times.
2. How can I better debug this error?

Answer (score 0):

Comparing your code with my code from the last project.

I would make a safer cast in the beginning (you will be protected from some unexpected state):

```
if let trans = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction
```

Then you I would also correct

```
    default:
        println("updatedTransactions: \(trans.transactionState.rawValue)")
        queue.finishTransaction(trans)
```

because you can also have `SKPaymentTransactionStateDeferred` from 8.0 and it should be finished.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I added those edits but still crashes. Putting a breakpoint at the end of the method is still caught however what happens after this i don't know.